# Ho to add additional obj to linker?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, linker, linker-errors

So, I have a CLR project & I wanna create and write UnitTest for  it. I done it as usual *(create NativeUnitTest project in this solution, add reference on my CLR project, add in Test project preferences -> C/C++ 'Additional include directories' & 'Additional #using directories' path where my CLR project)*. But when I run Tests, linker doesn't see CLR obj files & return **Error LINK2019**.
**How to fix it?**

Comment: what does this have to do with C++?

Comment: sorry, i removed flag 'C++', just I try to solve problem as soon as possible)

Comment: That ought to fail like that.  Only create a native unit test to test native code, create a *managed* unit test instead.

Comment: I can't 'cause CLR project and Managed Unit Tests incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple: just drug & drop required OBJ files to file-viewer, then they will be linked with required project.